# how can i get length of list in widget

Tags: flutter, dart, cubit

I can't get the length of the list  in the widget although I wrote everything correct

this is my cubit

```
class AppCubit extends Cubit<NewsStates> {
  AppCubit() : super(NewsInit());

  static AppCubit get(context) => BlocProvider.of(context);
  MianTeams? mianTeams;
  void getTimes() {
    emit(NewsLoding());
    DioHelper.getData(
            Query: {"action": "get_teams", "league_id": "141", "APIkey": api})
        .then((value) {
      mianTeams = MianTeams.fromJson(value.data);
////////////////+++++  i can get the length here in cubit 
      print(mianTeams!.team.length);
  
      emit(NewsSucsess());
    }).catchError((onError) {
      print(onError.toString());
      emit(NewsErorr(onError.toString()));
    });
  }
```

this is my model

```
class MianTeams {
  List<TeamsModel> team = [];
  MianTeams.fromJson(List<dynamic> json) {
    json.forEach((e) {
      team.add(TeamsModel.fromJson(e));
    });
  }
}

class TeamsModel {
  String? teamKey;
  String? teamName;
  String? teamBadge;
  List<Players> players = [];
  TeamsModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    teamKey = json['team_key'];
    teamName = json['team_name'];
    teamBadge = json['team_badge'];
    json['players'].forEach((e) {
      players.add(Players.fromJson(e));
    });
  }
}
```

but in Widget I can't get the length to set the itemCount of List View separated

this is my  statelessWidget

```
class Teams extends StatelessWidget {
  const Teams({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocConsumer<AppCubit, NewsStates>(
        listener: (context, state) {},
        builder: (context, state) {
          //  print(AppCubit.get(context).mianTeams!.team.length);          
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(),
            body: ListView.separated(
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(),
                separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(),
                itemCount: AppCubit.get(context).mianTeams!.team.length), 
          );
        });
  }
}
```

I don't know what's wrong and I think I wrote everything correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `mianTeams` is null until after `getTimes()` is called and the response is received from your API. So when the ListView tries to build initially, it's trying to get the length of a null list.

Instead of storing `mianTeams` directly as a property of the Cubit, you should make it a property of one of your State classes. Probably `NewsSuccess` - then the list will always be available in that state. And if the Cubit is in a different state, you can display a loading indicator or something.

Your Cubit might then look something like this:

```
class AppCubit extends Cubit<NewsStates> {
  AppCubit() : super(NewsInit());

  static AppCubit get(context) => BlocProvider.of(context);

  void getTimes() {
    emit(NewsLoding());
    DioHelper.getData(
            Query: {"action": "get_teams", "league_id": "141", "APIkey": api})
        .then((value) {
      final mianTeams = MianTeams.fromJson(value.data);
  
      emit(NewsSucsess(mianTeams: mianTeams));
    }).catchError((onError) {
      print(onError.toString());
      emit(NewsErorr(onError.toString()));
    });
  }
}
```

And your widget might be something like:

```
class Teams extends StatelessWidget {
  const Teams({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocConsumer<AppCubit, NewsStates>(
        listener: (context, state) {},
        builder: (context, state) {        
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(),
            body: _buildBody(state),
        });
  }

  Widget _buildBody(NewsStates state) {
    if (state is NewsError) {
      // For example
      return Text("Error: ${state.message}");
    } else if (state is NewsLoding) {
      // For example
      return const CircularProgressIndicator();
    } else if (state is NewsSuccess) {
      return ListView.separated(
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(),
          separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(),
          itemCount: state.mianTeams.team.length), 
      );
    } else {
      // Handle any other possible states you have
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `state` from builder

```dart
itemCount: state.mianTeams?.team.length,
```